# Adding extra graphic to a a UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I have a UITableViewCell setup and i'd like to add a graphic on the right hand side with a number inside it (similar to the way mail shows how many new mail messages you have)

So the UITableViewCell would look something like this;

[image]

Is there a simple way to do this? Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Simply, just `addSubview` on our cell.

```
[cell.contentview addSubView : yourIcon];
```

Make sure that your icon set at the right coordinate before you add it to your cell.